# fullTemplateTypeCheck for Angular 9. Incompatible types

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have working Angular (+ Angular Material) 9.1.0 application. I tried to add additional type checking in tsconfig.json for my project:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true
  },
```

And I had an error in this template element during build:

```
  <textarea matInput placeholder="{{ 'test.description' | translate}}" matAutosizeMinRows="3" matTextareaAutosize formControlName="description"></textarea>
```

The error message is correct:

```
error TS2326: Types of property 'matAutosizeMinRows' are incompatible.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Because matAutosizeMinRows is declared as number:

```
export declare class MatTextareaAutosize extends CdkTextareaAutosize {
    get matAutosizeMinRows(): number;
```

However if replace "3" with 3 in the template then error still remains.

The only way to fix that is to surround property into square brackets:

```
  <textarea matInput placeholder="{{ 'test.description' | translate}}" [matAutosizeMinRows]="3" matTextareaAutosize formControlName="description"></textarea>
```

Is that correct behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is the correct behaviour.

Without the square brackets, you are setting a value via the HTML attribute. By definition this is a string.

With the square brackets you are passing the literal value, which is a number.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ogvuhj